# No contiene ninguna definicion publica para GetNumeric ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Alguien que me pueda orientar a corregir este error, este se presenta en el (foreach) y hasta el momento no he podido corregirlo, de igual forma pongo el código de mi clsEntity, donde están las propiedades [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

```
@model model.entity.Alumno

@{
 ViewBag.Title = "inicio";
}

<h2>inicio</h2>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Codigo</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Apellido</th>
    <th>Telefono</th>
</tr>
@foreach (var objAlumno in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@objAlumno.IdAlumno </td>
        <td>@objAlumno.Nombre </td>
        <td>@objAlumno.Apellido1 </td>
        <td>@objAlumno.Telefono1 </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace model.entity
{
  public class Alumno
{
    public int idAlumno;
    public string nombre;
    public string Apellido;
    public string Telefono;
    //obtener errores del sistema
    public int estado;


    public int IdAlumno
    {
        get { return idAlumno; }
        set { idAlumno = value; }
    }
    public string Nombre
    {
        get { return nombre; }
        set { nombre = value; }
    }
     public string Apellido1
    {
        get { return Apellido; }
        set { Apellido = value; }
    }
     public string Telefono1
     {
         get { return Telefono; }
         set { Telefono = value; }
     }
     public int Estado
     {
         get { return estado; }
         set { estado = value; }
     }
     public Alumno()
     { 
     }
     public void _Alumno(int idAlumno)
     {
         this.idAlumno = idAlumno;
     }
     public Alumno(int idalumno, string nombre, string Apellido, string  Telefono)
     {
         this.IdAlumno = idAlumno;
         this.Nombre = nombre;
         this.Apellido1 = Apellido;
         this.Telefono1 = Telefono;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Ya lo soluciones, @model List<model.entity.Alumno>, la verdad es un ejercicio que estoy haciendo en tiempos libre en mi trabajo y apenas voy empezando en este rollo por lo cual me falta practica pero me doy cuenta que en esta página, voy a prender mas.

Comment: por último en la parte de Razor como puedo poner un boton, eliminar, insertar y actualizar.

Comment: lo que pasa que tengo un, cls donde están mis métodos. de eliminar, actualizar, insertar- En mi vista como puedo mandar a llamar esos métodos para que yo pueda eliminar,insertar, actualizar los registros que están en la BD, estoy haciendo algo así, por ahora.

  @if (Model.IndexOf,objAlumno.idAlumno > 0)
    {
    <a href="~/E/Eliminar/@objAlumno.idAlumno" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
    }

Comment: Ya publique mi pregunta. 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/220397/como-mandar-a-llamar-mis-m%C3%A9todos-insertar-eliminar-actualizar-en-razor

Comment: @Xique Gracias por el apoyo :D

Comment: @Xique claro que si, asi aprendo mas, gracias :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `foreach` solo funciona como te pone en el error con clases que tengan definido el `GetEnumerator`. Normalmente el `foreach` se suele usar sobre una `List` o un `Iqueryable` o algo así. Comprueba que no quieres hacer `foreach` sobre una `List<Alumno>` de alumnos