# Como mandar a llamar mis métodos, insertar,eliminar,actualizar en "Razor"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

La verdad he manejado muy poco asp,net. pero en esta ocacion quiero que me puedan orientar a como mandar a llamar desde Razor mis métodos insertar,eliminar,actualizar, para que pueda eliminar los Registros que están alojados en la BD, dejo mi vista y mi cls insertar,eliminar,actualizar, hice algo como lo que esta en la parte de abajo pero no me funciona .

```html
 @if (Model.IndexOf,objAlumno.idAlumno > 0)
            {
            <a href="~/E/Eliminar/@objAlumno.idAlumno" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
            }
```

```
@model List<model.entity.Alumno>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "inicio";
        Layout = null;
    }


    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Codigo</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellido</th>
            <th>Telefono</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var objAlumno in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@objAlumno.IdAlumno </td>
                <td>@objAlumno.Nombre </td>
                <td>@objAlumno.Apellido1 </td>
                <td>@objAlumno.Telefono1 </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
         @if (Model.IndexOf,objAlumno.idAlumno > 0)
        {
        <a href="~/E/Eliminar/@objAlumno.idAlumno" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
        }

        }

    </table>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using model.entity;

namespace mdel.neg
{
    public class AlumnoDao:obligatorio<Alumno>
    {
        private Conexion objConexion;
        private SqlCommand conn;

        public AlumnoDao()
        {
            objConexion = Conexion.SaberEstado();
        }

        public void crear(Alumno objAlumno)
        {
            string crear = "insert into Persona(idAlumno,nombre,Apellido,Telefono)values('" + objAlumno.IdAlumno + "'+'" + objAlumno.Nombre + "'+'" + objAlumno.Apellido1 + "''" + objAlumno.Telefono1 + "')";
            try
            {
                conn = new SqlCommand(crear, objConexion.getcon());
                objConexion.getcon().Open();
                conn.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                objConexion.getcon().Close();
                objConexion.cerrarConexion();

            }
        }
        public void Actualizar(Alumno objAlumno)
        {
            string actualizar = "update Persona set nombre='" + objAlumno.IdAlumno + "',Apellido='" + objAlumno.Apellido1 + "',Telefono='" + objAlumno.Telefono1 + "' Where idAlumno ='" + objAlumno.IdAlumno + "'";
            try
            {
                conn = new SqlCommand(actualizar, objConexion.getcon());
                objConexion.getcon().Open();
                conn.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                objConexion.getcon().Close();
                objConexion.cerrarConexion();
            }
        }
        public void Eliminar(Alumno objAlumno)
        {
            string eliminar = "'delete from Persona where idAlumno ='" + objAlumno.IdAlumno + "'";

            try
            {
                conn = new SqlCommand(eliminar, objConexion.getcon());
                objConexion.getcon().Open();
                conn.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                objConexion.getcon().Close();
                objConexion.cerrarConexion();
            }
        }
        public bool find(Alumno objAlumno)
        {
            bool ExistenRegistros;
            string find = "select * from Persona where idAlumno = '" + objAlumno.IdAlumno + "'";
            try
            {
                conn = new SqlCommand(find, objConexion.getcon());
                objConexion.getcon().Open();
                SqlDataReader read = conn.ExecuteReader();
                ExistenRegistros = read.Read();
                if (ExistenRegistros)
                {
                    objAlumno.IdAlumno = Convert.ToInt32(read[0].ToString());
                    objAlumno.Nombre = read[1].ToString();
                    objAlumno.Apellido1 = read[2].ToString();
                    objAlumno.Telefono1 = read[3].ToString();

                    objAlumno.Estado = 99;

                }
                else
                {
                    objAlumno.Estado = 1;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            return ExistenRegistros;

        }
        public List<Alumno> findAll()
        {
            List<Alumno> LisAlumno = new List<Alumno>();

            string findAll = "select * from Persona";
            try
            {

                conn = new SqlCommand(findAll, objConexion.getcon());
                objConexion.getcon().Open();
                SqlDataReader read = conn.ExecuteReader();
                while (read.Read())
                {

                    Alumno objAlumno = new Alumno();
                    objAlumno.IdAlumno = Convert.ToInt32(read[0].ToString());
                    objAlumno.Nombre = read[1].ToString();
                    objAlumno.Apellido1 = read[2].ToString();
                    objAlumno.Telefono1 = read[3].ToString();
                    LisAlumno.Add(objAlumno);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                objConexion.getcon().Close();
                objConexion.cerrarConexion();
            }
            return LisAlumno;
        }

                //}
                //catch (Exception)
                //{

                //    throw;

                //}           
                //return LisAlumno;

        public void actualizar(Alumno obj)
        {
            throw new NoNullAllowedException();
        }
        public void eliminar(Alumno obj)
        {
            throw new NoNullAllowedException();
        }
        public List<Alumno> finAll()
        {
            throw new NoNullAllowedException();
        }
        public void actualzar(Alumno obj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer que es lo mas sencillo es poner un [@html.ActionLink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201341/6553113) para cada elemento que te redirija al método ya sea que mande a una vista(actualizar,insertar) o directamente a la acción en el caso de eliminar quedaría mas o menos así tu vista:

```
@model List<model.entity.Alumno>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "inicio";
        Layout = null;
    }

   <td>
                   @Html.ActionLink("Alumnos", "Create")   
   </td>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Codigo</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellido</th>
            <th>Telefono</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var objAlumno in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@objAlumno.IdAlumno </td>
                <td>@objAlumno.Nombre </td>
                <td>@objAlumno.Apellido1 </td>
                <td>@objAlumno.Telefono1 </td>
                <td>
                  @Html.ActionLink("Alumnos", "Delete", new { id =  objAlumno.id })
               </td>
                <td>
                  @Html.ActionLink("Alumnos", "Edit", new { id =  objAlumno.id })
               </td>
            </tr>

        }

    </table>
```

Como para agregar un nuevo alumno no necesitarías ningún parámetro pues solo necesitas un botón.
Si necesitas mas detalles [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application) te dejo la documentación de como hacer un CRUD.